# Created a function to get image url if there are images in a slide & "[ ]" if no images are there in a slide

Tags: html, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup, append

```
def get_urls(slide_urls):

    no_images = []
    image_links= [] 
    html = urlopen(slide_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    if soup.findAll('img') == []:
            print('no images in the slide')
            no_images.append(image_links)

    else:                         
        for res in soup.findAll('img'):
            print(res.get('src'))
            list_var = slide_urls.split('/')

            resource = list_var[0:-1]
            resource = "/".join(resource)
            image_links.append((resource + '/' + str(res.get('src'))))

            #image_links = list(set(image_links))

            image_links.append(no_images)

    return image_links
```

Ideally here I should be getting 9 rows in column. 8 for slide which has 8 images and 1 "[]" for a slide which does not have any images but I am getting 16 rows.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: add your full code and a link to site, which you're trying to scrape.

Comment: Hey @DmitriyFialkovskiy
Thanks for showing interest this problem.
It has been resolved now.